# How to check if comma separated strings have duplicate values in php

Tags: php, string

I have a variable that contains comma separated strings and I would like to create a check if this variable has duplicate strings inside without converting it into an array. If it would make it any easier, each comma separated strings have 3 characters.

example.

```
$str = 'PTR, PTR, SDP, LTP';
```

logic: if any of the strings has a duplicate value then display an error.

Comment: Nice specification! So what have you tried to code? SO is not a **free coding site**

Comment: 1) Have you tried something ? 2) Sounds like homework or a job interview question.

Comment: It's just something that I am working on. Well, I tried to explode the string and convert it into an array then loop through it but Is it possible to just not   convert the strings into an array? Is there a php function that could do the job or any other solution?

Comment: Why do you need to do it without converting to an array? `explode` will do that easily, and then you can use `array_unique` to tell if the array contains any duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just use [`strtok()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) to loop through each token of your string, with `,` as delimiter. Then use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to check if the token is more than once in the string.

```
<?php

    $str = "PTR, PTR, SDP, LTP";

    $tok = strtok($str, ", ");
    $subStrStart = 0;

    while ($tok !== false) {
        preg_match_all("/\b" . preg_quote($tok, "/") . "\b/", substr($str, $subStrStart), $m);
        if(count($m[0]) >= 2)
            echo $tok . " found more than 1 times, exaclty: " . count($m[0]) . "<br>";
        $subStrStart += strlen($tok);
        $tok = strtok(", ");
    }

?>
```

output:

```
PTR found more than 1 times, exaclty: 2
```

Comment: @JoseDiago You're welcome. (I still don't know why you would need this)

Answer (score 0):

You are going to run into some issues with just using `explode`. In your example, if you use explode, you'll get:

```
'PTR', ' PTR', ' SDP', ' LTP'
```

You have to map trim in there.

```
<?php
// explode on , and remove spaces
$myArray = array_map('trim', explode(',', $str));

// get a count of all the values into a new array
$stringCount = array_count_values($myArray);

// sum of all the $stringCount values should equal size of $stringCount IE: they are all 1
$hasDupes = array_sum($stringCount) != count($stringCount);
?>
```

Comment: Besides that your code has a syntax error in it I think you missed that: ***without converting it into an array***

Comment: @Rizier123 He may prefer this code as it's a bit easier to understand and runs about 2.5 times faster. It could be optimized even more if you know that the separator will always be ', '. In fact, it's 5.5 times faster if you can do `$myArray = explode(', ', $str);` There really is no reason not to convert it to an array, since PHP works with arrays fairly efficiently.